# background style from mysqli database

Tags: php, html, background-image

I'm trying to add background image property do div. I know that I can display normal image from database like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" />';
```

but what about adding background to div? I tried, I really did but just my code doesn't work so i ask how to do that?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    require_once('config.inc.php');

    $sql = "SELECT id, title, author, image FROM articles ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<a href="'.$row["id"].'">';
                echo '<div class="module" style="background:'.base64_encode($row["image"]).'">';
                  echo '<h3 class="article-title">'.$row["title"].'<br />'.$row["author"].'</h3>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</a>';
        }
    } else  echo "Wystąpił błąd z bazą danych";

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Try and apply the same as you did for the image, adding `data:image/jpeg;base64` that should work.

Comment: `var_dump($row["image"]);` shows what and also your HTML source; what do those reveal?

Answer (score 0):

"`DIV`" tag does'nt support an a base64 format. If you want to show an image in, you have to use the `background-image` property of CSS.

Example:

```
<div style="background-image:url(<?=$YourBase64?>);padding:50px;background-size:cover;background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

You can see more about it in: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: What is $YourBase64? So should be like this: 
echo '<div class="module" style="background-image:url(<?=$row["image"])?>)">';
?

Comment: Just like you said! Luck.

Comment: Well it doesn't work and show me error in console: GET http://localhost/op/%3C?=$row[ 403 (Forbidden)

At the HTML DOM inspect it looks like this: <div class="module" style="background-image:url(<?=$row[" image"])?>

Comment: You are already in the string you are echoing.. <?= ?> is the shorthand for echo but you don't need that if you're already echoing.  You need to concatenate $row['image'] into the right place in your string.

Comment: I changed it one more time, now its: echo '<div class="post" style="background-image: url(\'' . $row["image"] . '\')">'; 
it should be good but still doesnt work correctly. It displays whole page of odd signs instead of an image. Plsease help!

Comment: Could you send me the base64 code, please? Probably the code is wrong.

Comment: @HeroldNixell its a problem with your concatenation.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are not telling your CSS to use a base64 encoded image, also remember in CSS you need the url() function:

```
echo '<div class="module" style="background-image:url(data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . ')">';
```